# How to Backup/Shrink the image of my working Raspbian SD Card

Tags: raspbian, image

I want to shrink the image to minimise storage and to efficiently distribute this image to others who may have smaller SD Cards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many users ask how they can produce a small customised image that can be used to create new SD Cards and/or how they can shrink an image to make a compact backup of a running system.

I have found a [backup tool](https://raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1528736) which makes installable images on the Pi itself.

> The original tool has changed, and keeps changing, so I can not guarantee the download - particularly as the changes are undocumented.
> My script, below is in regular use

It also has utilities to mount and shrink images.

This may be useful to others

The documentation that comes with it is very brief so I note the following:-

1. Extract the utilities into any directory and make scripts executable.
2. Mount an `ext4` formatted partition on your Pi in `/mnt` or `/media` (any format which allows large files and is supported by Pi e.g. exFAT or a network drive can be used).
3. For the initial run you will be prompted for a Backup Image name e.g. `/mnt/Image/BusterBackup.img`
4. You will be prompted for a Image **ROOT filesystem size** (in MB), this can be **0** for smallest possible or blank for full backup.
   For a compact image use the **Used** from `df -H --type=ext4 --output=fstype,used` plus 300
5. On subsequent runs enter the path of the Backup Image to incrementally update.

> NOTE The image created will not auto resize on boot, and should be maximised in `raspi-config`.

An example of the commands I used:-

```bsh
# Mount USB
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/Image/
# Mount network drive
sudo mount.cifs //10.1.2.107/Images /mnt/Image -o user=UUU
# Update backup
sudo image-utils/image-backup /mnt/Image/BusterBackup.img
# Mount backup
sudo image-utils/image-mount /mnt/Image/BusterBackup.img  MountedImages
When done, run:
sudo umount MountedImages; sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
# Compress backup
sudo gzip -9kN /mnt/Image/StretchBackup.img
```

I have slightly modified the original `image-backup` (to copy mountpoints), to correctly calculate partition offsets and sizes and added a couple of comments.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Original https://raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1528736
# 2019-09-26    Modified to set size of boot sector

trap '{ stty sane; echo ""; errexit "Aborted"; }' SIGINT SIGTERM

ADDBLK=0

# Set BOOT_SIZE_MB to the Desired boot sector size (in MB) - should be multiple of 4MB
BOOT_SIZE_MB=256
BOOTSIZEM=$BOOT_SIZE_MB'M'

BOOTBEG=8192
BOOT_SIZE="$((BOOT_SIZE_MB * 1024 * 1024))"
ROUND_SIZE="$((4 * 1024 * 1024))"
# Ensure root sector starts on an Erase Block Boundary (4MB)
ROOTBEG=$(((BOOT_SIZE + ROUND_SIZE -1) / ROUND_SIZE * ROUND_SIZE / 512 + BOOTBEG))

MNTPATH="/tmp/img-backup-mnt"

ONEMB=$((1024 * 1024))

# create BOOT loop device
mkloop1()
{
  local INFO1=""
  local SIZE1=0
  local START1=0

  sync
  INFO1="$(sfdisk -d "${IMGFILE}")"
  START1=$(grep type=c <<< "${INFO1}" | sed -n 's|^.*start=\s\+\([0-9]\+\).*$|\1|p')
  SIZE1=$(grep type=c <<< "${INFO1}" | sed -n 's|^.*size=\s\+\([0-9]\+\).*$|\1|p')
  LOOP1="$(losetup -f --show -o $((${START1} * 512)) --sizelimit $((${SIZE1} * 512)) "${IMGFILE}")"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    errexit "Unable to create BOOT loop device"
  fi
}

rmloop1()
{
  if [ "${LOOP1}" != "" ]; then
    sync
    losetup -d "${LOOP1}"
    LOOP1=""
 fi
}

# create ROOT loop device
mkloop2()
{
  local INFO2=""
  local SIZE2=0
  local START2=0

  sync
  INFO2="$(sfdisk -d "${IMGFILE}")"
  START2=$(grep type=83 <<< "${INFO2}" | sed -n 's|^.*start=\s\+\([0-9]\+\).*$|\1|p')
  SIZE2=$(grep type=83 <<< "${INFO2}" | sed -n 's|^.*size=\s\+\([0-9]\+\).*$|\1|p')
  LOOP2="$(losetup -f --show -o $((${START2} * 512)) --sizelimit $((${SIZE2} * 512)) "${IMGFILE}")"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    errexit "Unable to create ROOT loop device"
  fi
}

rmloop2()
{
  if [ "${LOOP2}" != "" ]; then
    sync
    losetup -d "${LOOP2}"
    LOOP2=""
  fi
}

# Mount Image partitions
mntimg()
{
  MNTED=TRUE
  if [ ! -d "${MNTPATH}/" ]; then
    mkdir "${MNTPATH}/"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      errexit "Unable to make ROOT partition mount point"
    fi
  fi
  mkloop2
  mount "${LOOP2}" "${MNTPATH}/"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    errexit "Unable to mount image ROOT partition"
  fi
  if [ ! -d "${MNTPATH}/boot/" ]; then
    mkdir -p "${MNTPATH}/boot/"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      errexit "Unable to make BOOT partition mount point"
    fi
  fi
  mkloop1
  mount "${LOOP1}" "${MNTPATH}/boot/"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    errexit "Unable to mount image BOOT partition"
  fi
}

umntimg()
{
  umount "${MNTPATH}/boot/"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    errexit "Unable to unmount image BOOT partition"
  fi
  rmloop1
  umount "${MNTPATH}/"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    errexit "Unable to unmount image ROOT partition"
  fi
  rmloop2
  rm -r "${MNTPATH}/"
  MNTED=FALSE
}

errexit()
{
  echo ""
  echo "$1"
  echo ""
  if [ "${MNTED}" = "TRUE" ]; then
    umount "${MNTPATH}/boot/" &> /dev/null
    umount "${MNTPATH}/" &> /dev/null
    rm -rf "${MNTPATH}/" &> /dev/null
  fi
  rmloop1
  rmloop2
  exit 1
}

LOOP1=""
LOOP2=""
MNTED=FALSE

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
  errexit "$0 must be run as root user"
fi

PGMNAME="$(basename $0)"
for PID in $(pidof -x -o %PPID "${PGMNAME}"); do
  if [ ${PID} -ne $$ ]; then
    errexit "${PGMNAME} is already running"
  fi
done

rsync --version &> /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  errexit "rsync not installed (run: apt-get install rsync)"
fi

if command -v systemctl > /dev/null && systemctl | grep -q '\-\.mount'; then
  SYSTEMD=1
elif [ -f /etc/init.d/cron ] && [ ! -h /etc/init.d/cron ]; then
  SYSTEMD=0
else
  errexit "Unrecognized init system"
fi

if [ ${SYSTEMD} -eq 1 ]; then
  ROOT_PART="$(mount | sed -n 's|^/dev/\(.*\) on / .*|\1|p')"
else
  if [ ! -h /dev/root ]; then
    errexit "/dev/root does not exist or is not a symlink"
  fi
  ROOT_PART="$(readlink /dev/root)"
fi

ROOT_TYPE=$(blkid "/dev/${ROOT_PART}" | sed -n 's|^.*TYPE="\(\S\+\)".*|\1|p')

ROOT_DEV="${ROOT_PART:0:(${#ROOT_PART} - 1)}"
if [ "${ROOT_DEV}" = "mmcblk0p" ]; then
  ROOT_DEV="${ROOT_DEV:0:(${#ROOT_DEV} - 1)}"
fi

PTUUID="$(blkid "/dev/${ROOT_DEV}" | sed -n 's|^.*PTUUID="\(\S\+\)".*|\1|p')"

DEVSIZE=$(blockdev --getsize64 "/dev/${ROOT_PART}")
BLKSIZE=$(blockdev --getbsz "/dev/${ROOT_PART}")
BLKCNT=$((${DEVSIZE} / ${BLKSIZE}))
INFO="$(df | grep /dev/root)"
DFKSIZE=$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "${INFO}")
DFKFREE=$(awk '{print $4}' <<< "${INFO}")
ROOTSIZE=$((${BLKCNT} * ${BLKSIZE}))
ROOTUSED=$(((${DFKSIZE} - ${DFKFREE}) * 1024))
IRFSMIN=$(((${ROOTUSED} + (${ADDBLK} * ${BLKSIZE}) + (${ONEMB} - 1)) / ${ONEMB}))
IRFSMAX=$(((${ROOTSIZE} + (${ONEMB} - 1)) / ${ONEMB}))

IMGFILE="$1"
if [ "${IMGFILE}" = "" ]; then
# Create Image file
  while :
  do
    echo ""
    read -r -e -i "${IMGFILE}" -p "Image file to create? " IMGFILE
    if [ "${IMGFILE}" = "" ]; then
      continue
    elif [[ ! "${IMGFILE}" =~ ^/mnt/.*$ && ! "${IMGFILE}" =~ ^/media/.*$ ]]; then
      echo ""
      echo "${IMGFILE} does not begin with /mnt/ or /media/"
      continue
    fi
    if [ -d "${IMGFILE}" ]; then
      echo ""
      echo "${IMGFILE} is a directory"
    elif [ -f "${IMGFILE}" ]; then
      echo ""
      echo -n "${IMGFILE} already exists, Ok to delete (y/n)? "
      while read -r -n 1 -s answer; do
        if [[ "${answer}" = [yYnN] ]]; then
          echo "${answer}"
          if [[ "${answer}" = [yY] ]]; then
            break 2
          else
            break 1
          fi
        fi
      done
    else
      break
    fi
  done
  IRFSSIZE=""
  while :
  do
    echo ""
    read -r -e -i "${IRFSSIZE}" -p "Image ROOT filesystem size (MB) [${IRFSMAX}]? " IRFSSIZE
    if [ "${IRFSSIZE}" = "" ]; then
      IRFSSIZE=${IRFSMAX}
      break
    elif [ ${IRFSSIZE} -ge ${IRFSMIN} ]; then
      break
    else
      echo ""
      echo "Requested image ROOT filesystem size (${IRFSSIZE}) is too small (Minimum = ${IRFSMIN})"
      IRFSSIZE=${IRFSMIN}
    fi
  done
  echo ""
  echo -n "Create ${IMGFILE} [${IRFSSIZE} MB] (y/n)? "
  while read -r -n 1 -s answer; do
    if [[ "${answer}" = [yYnN] ]]; then
      echo "${answer}"
      if [[ "${answer}" = [yY] ]]; then
        break
      else
        errexit "Aborted"
      fi
    fi
  done
  if [ -f "${IMGFILE}" ]; then
    rm "${IMGFILE}"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      errexit "Unable to delete existing image file"
    fi
  fi
  ROOTEND=$((${ROOTBEG} + ((${IRFSSIZE} * ${ONEMB}) / 512) - 1))
  truncate -s $(((${ROOTEND} + 1) * 512)) "${IMGFILE}"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    errexit "Unable to create image file"
  fi
# create image/partitions
  sync
  fdisk "${IMGFILE}" <<EOF > /dev/null
p
n
p
1
${BOOTBEG}
+${BOOTSIZEM}
t
c
p
n
p
2
${ROOTBEG}
${ROOTEND}
p
w
EOF

  mkloop1
  mkloop2
  mkfs.vfat "${LOOP1}" > /dev/null
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    errexit "Unable to create image BOOT filesystem"
  fi
  dosfsck "${LOOP1}" > /dev/null
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    errexit "Image BOOT filesystem appears corrupted"
  fi
  if [ "${ROOT_TYPE}" = "f2fs" ]; then
    mkfs.f2fs "${LOOP2}" > /dev/null
  else
    mkfs.ext4 -q -b ${BLKSIZE} "${LOOP2}" > /dev/null
  fi
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    errexit "Unable to create image ROOT filesystem"
  fi
  rmloop2
  rmloop1
# Initialise image PARTUUID
  fdisk "${IMGFILE}" <<EOF > /dev/null
p
x
i
0x${PTUUID}
r
p
w
EOF
# Create empty directories in image root partition
  mntimg
  mkdir "${MNTPATH}/dev/" "${MNTPATH}/media/" "${MNTPATH}/mnt/" "${MNTPATH}/proc/" "${MNTPATH}/run/" "${MNTPATH}/sys/" "${MNTPATH}/tmp/"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    errexit "Unable to create image directories"
  fi
  chmod a+rwxt "${MNTPATH}/tmp/"
  umntimg
  echo ""
  echo "Starting full backup (for incremental backups, run: $0 ${IMGFILE})"
# END of create image/partitions
else

# Check existing Image
  if [[ ! "${IMGFILE}" =~ ^/mnt/.*$ && ! "${IMGFILE}" =~ ^/media/.*$ ]]; then
    errexit "${IMGFILE} does not begin with /mnt/ or /media/"
  fi
  if [ -d "${IMGFILE}" ]; then
    errexit "${IMGFILE} is a directory"
  elif [ ! -f "${IMGFILE}" ]; then
    errexit "${IMGFILE} not found"
  fi
  echo "Starting incremental backup to ${IMGFILE}"
fi

# rsync root partition
mntimg
sync
rsync -aDH --partial --numeric-ids --delete --force --exclude "${MNTPATH}" --exclude '/dev' --exclude '/media' --exclude '/mnt/*/*' --exclude '/proc' --exclude '/run' --exclude '/sys' \
--exclude '/tmp' --exclude 'lost\+found' --exclude '/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules' --exclude '/var/lib/asterisk/astdb.sqlite3-journal' / "${MNTPATH}/"
if [[ $? -ne 0 && $? -ne 24 ]]; then
  errexit "Unable to create backup"
fi
sync
umntimg
```

Comment: Extremely useful! I read the forum posts just now, and thank you for highlighting this. I see also that the script has been put up as a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/seamusdemora/RonR-RaspberryPi-image-utils), but with **no support** (the repo creator is not the author). I would like to nominate YOU to fork this repo, and take on support of it. All in favor? Aye - it's unanimous - you are now the official maintainer! Seriously though, the code should be adopted and maintained - and documented!

Comment: So should I better use the fixed image-backup code from here? Can you please explain what problems were expected from the repo version?

Comment: @ramiwi I explained the few changes I made in the Answer above. I can't comment on other code. Ron has no changelog, only has a zip download and sparse documentation. The code itself is clever, but rather obscure in places. Before using it I examined every line to work out what it is doing. As Ron's code changes frequently, but without explanation you have to make up your own mind. The fundamental `rsync` code is quite standard and once you have an image updates are fast and safe.

Comment: @Milliways In case I dont need it as scheduled job, is it simpler/safer to dump the sd card offline on an external system using DD/Win32DiskImager and then use PiShrink to minimize it?