# Can we create raspberry sd card image to only the file size it is using not the complete card size images

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I made an image of 16GB card which is now a 14.8 GB which is exact to the card memory , can we make image with file size used like it is currently using 6GB only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following procedure to make backup images.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103991/8697

This can be used to make minimal sized, full size or arbitrary sized images.
The prompts for image size on initial backup; subsequent backups update the image.

I backup my 32GB cards to a 13GB image (which can be compressed to less than 5GB for archival).