# What is the difference between an operating system ISO that can be flashed to a harddrive, vs a copy of an installed OS produced with DD

Tags: image

I have to provision multiple Raspberry Pi's, and I thought I could simply copy one's memory card using dd to a file, and use that file to flash multiple new memory cards. I've tried this multiple times and it hasn't worked.

I'm planning on forking https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen and adding what I need using that, but I'm curious why my original approach didn't work. What is different about these files, the file I created using dd, vs. the Raspbian ISO file that I flash onto the memory card?

I'd also like to be clear and differentiate from a Live CD. I am copying the OS directly to the Pi's "harddrive" (the micro SD card) in both cases.

I created the image in an Ubuntu VirtualBox VM, with the Micro SD card mounted as a USB device into the VM

Originally posted on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662569/what-is-the-difference-between-an-operating-system-iso-that-can-be-flashed-to-a), someone over there suggested that I need to copy, or setup somehow, the master boot record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly the Pi **DOES NOT** use "ISO"

There should be no significant difference between a downloaded OS image and one produced by `dd` **assuming you did it correctly**.

To be clear an image of a working OS will be significantly larger than a downloaded image because it will be expanded on use.

Done correctly the `dd` will be the size of the SD Card, and because even nominally identical cards may differ slightly in size you may not be able to restore to different SD Cards.

I routinely make backup images of my SD Cards and use them to create new SD Cards, although I no longer use `dd` but a more efficient [Backup image of SD Card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103991/8697) method.

Comment: thank you for this.  "assuming you did it correctly", i'm sure if there is a "wrong way" I did that. I will try your script, thank you