# Back up system to hdd

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh, linux, backup

I have a hdd connected to one of my raspberry pi’s that is on raspbian, now I would like to be able to backup my Linux machines 2 or more to that hdd on a regular basis to help with system restores. Rsync would probably be a good start from my searching but I need a hand with the proper syntax and switches .

Comment: First question I would ask is - are the two target machines able to be backed up live or will you do better to back up data only and rebuild the O/S from scratch?

Comment: The 2 or more was just in general, however I actually have two machines one kali machine and another in a virtual box environment , so I believe that the main Os would be able to be backed up live, honestly I’m not sure. But backing up the data is fine I could reinstall a system and if all of my configurations were stored somewhere that would be just fine with me , drivers, software etc..

Answer (score 1):

I use the code in [Backup image of SD Card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103991/8697) to perform incremental backups.

You can backup to a network drive or local HDD.

There are a number of other examples using `rsync` e.g. 
[can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28087/8697) creates full backup images to attached HDD.

(Some of the other Answers in [Can a Raspberry Pi be used to create a backup of itself?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself) need to be used with caution)

Comment: +1 for "used with caution."  *However* you back something up, you must test that a proper restore can be performed from your backup.  You don't want to find out your backup drive is really a paperweight at a time when you *really need it.*