# resizing the /boot partition after no space left on device

Tags: boot, raspbian-buster, partition, resize

After some errors on the many pis I manage with raspbian buster, I had some no space left on device issues and saw that the /boot partition has only 54M `/dev/mmcblk0p1   43M   23M   21M  53% /boot`. I resized it after having moved and shrinked the `/` partition with `gparted`. On resizing the `/boot` partition `gparted` threw me an error but seemed to have done something anyways...
I now want to `resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p1` but it doesnt' work

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p1                                                                                                                    
resize2fs 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)                                                                                                                                                                              
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mmcblk0p1                                                                                                                                 
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clean up my /boot partition?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/114533/how-to-clean-up-my-boot-partition)

Comment: @Milliways no, 54MB is too small even cleaned thx

Comment: The Answer "you could use the procedure I use to create a [Backup image of SD Card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103991/8697)" does work, because it creates a fresh image with the correct partitions (even correcting the minor error in Foundation images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the solution was to resize the boot partition after resizing the slash partition smaller and move it right.
Resizing the boot partition needs a

1. mount partition on `/tmp/some_dir`
2. copy data to it `cp -rp /mnt/mounted_boot_partition/* /tmp/some_dir/`
3. delete the partition with gparted or any other tool
4. create a bigger partition with boot flag (am not sure its mandatory)
5. restore data `cp -rp /tmp/some_dir/* /mnt/mounted_boot_partition/`
6. umount `sync && /mnt/mounted_boot_partition/`
7. try it!

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

`resize2fs` will resize ext2,ext3 and ext4 filesystems. Your boot partition is not any of those. It is a vfat. Therefore `fatresize` is the command to use.

Call me paranoid, but your remark:

> gparted threw me an error but seemed to have done something anyways

gave me the idea that something is not going as you planned.

Shrinking the root partition takes room at the end. The `/boot` is at the beginning. So probably, the `/boot` and the root partition are still contiguous and therefore, the partition for `/boot` is probably not enlarged (which might be the error message) and therefore, `fatresize` will probably do nothing. But that is just based on what I have in my Pis.

Comment: thx, see my complete answer, at the end donno if its about `gparted` version I have but had to delete/recreate/restore-data for the `/boot` partition

Answer (score 1):

You have presumably "updated" from a previous release - which is NOT supported.

Buster needs a larger boot partition.

You **CAN NOT** do this on the Pi although it can be done on a Linux computer.

You should do a fresh install.

If you search this Forum you will find similar questions.

Comment: Of course, but if you have hours configuring an image it worths doing an update and grow the boot partition.... I cannot afford doing a new image every time a new release gets out.... but thx, I saw it too!

Comment: @PhilippeGachoud New OS are only released every 2 years or so (Raspbian is on its 4th release since 2012) and it takes longer to "fix" than a fresh install, but if you want to do this see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114556/8697