# How to clone a Pi that has flash instead of an SD card

Tags: sd-card, backup, data-transfer, raspbian-lite, compute-module-3

I'm working with the Pi CM3+, which has 32GB of flash memory (at least my specific one does). While of course it needed an image on an SD card to initially boot, since then it has been operating solely off flash. Having configured everything and set up a bunch of programs the way I want them, I now want to create copies of the system to make multiple Pis with these settings and files. However, every search result I get assumes that the user is working with an SD card that can simply be plugged into a Windows machine, not onboard flash. Can I clone the flash to an SD card on the Pi itself? OS is Raspbian Lite, so no GUI.

Edit: Upon further research, the flash on the CM3+ uses the same pins as the SD card reader on the interface board, meaning both cannot be used simultaneously. I'm currently trying @Milliways' suggestion below

Comment: Try RonRs Pi imager. It will create a file of your current system that you can then use to make other images. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=247568 I've not tried it on flash though hence the comment not answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Backup/Shrink the image of my working Raspbian SD Card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103990/how-to-backup-shrink-the-image-of-my-working-raspbian-sd-card) Will work with **ANY** storage medium.