# How to repair an raspian installation

Tags: raspbian

I've seen a lot of questions like mine, but then the problem description is different, and so were the responses....

I installed a 3.5 inch LCD display, downloaded and installed the *wrong* drivers, so I then downloaded and installed the correct drivers, and the display worked perfectly ... until I touched it (touch screen) and a large spark fried the display. Now, I need to get back to my very-much-larger than 480x320 display, however ... Since I installed twice and the install does not bother with restoring a backup, just creating one, my backup was of the wrong installation, leaving me with no backup.

I have stepped through the backup/restore scripts and tried to reverse everything, however, I did not, or could not, recover completely. Apparently, something(s) got replaced and lost.

The RPi boots, the display comes up in the larger resolution, however, every program now takes 10-15 seconds to start up. Rather than hunting down the problem, I'd like to know if there is a way to reinstall Raspian without wiping out my stuff. Basically, this would look like system update to a new version, but it would be to the same version.

uname -a:
Linux  5.15.84-v7+ #1613 SMP Thu Jan 5 11:59:48 GMT 2023 armv71 GNU/Linux

Comment: Do you want it so that all your stuff you installed is still there? Because you could just copy the files you want to keep and put it back when you reinstall Raspian.

Comment: @Friendlygabe777, true, but there is all of the configuration that I've done in /etc, etc. (pun intended), and not knowing what every installation has installed, removed, tweaked.

Comment: ok, you did first check task manager/check the cpu/memory usage, correct? That could be slowing down the raspberry pi. You can see what you installed that caused this to happen.

Comment: Just do what the experienced users would do. Restore from your most recent working backup (preferably to a new SD Card) or do a fresh install. Learn from your experience and ensure you ALWAYS have a backup. I always keep at least 3 backups for each of my multiple OS.

Comment: It is easier (and certainly more reliable) to reinstall rather than attempt to repair. It is invariably faster - after all you can do a fresh install in a few hours.

Comment: I agree with @Milliways I always just reinstall when I get a fatal problem and I always just reinstall all the programs. If you don't want to always reinstall stuff, try what I'm attempting and make a script that has all the commands to reinstall everything you want. Just make sure to backup that script.

Comment: @Milliways - I mentioned that the backup was over-written. I have used systems in the past that have a "recovery" or "re-install" option in which drivers, executables, etc., are re-installed for the current version, leaving configuration files in place.

Comment: If you have 1 "backup" you ACTUALLY have a false sense of security. 2 is better but 3 is the recommended practice. Overwriting a single backup risks losing everything.

Comment: @Friendlygabe777 I did check for activity, everything was less than 5%, usually 0%.

Comment: @Milliways - The backup I relied on was the one the driver install created. I mistakenly presumed the install script would check for a backup and prompt for permission to over-write. I was wr... wr... wro ... wrong(!) As for creating these backups, a process I endorse, are you suggesting that I keep 3 backups of the entire system "disk"? How do you do that? The dd program? Do you tell it not to copy /dev/mem and then how is /dev/mem restored? I'm not arguing, just looking for the best practice for this platform since there does not seem to be a reinstall option.

Comment: I use a custom procedure - see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103991/8697 which generates a small customised image which can be installed by any of the normal installers . Since then I have modified my procedure for my own situation due to changes in Raspberry Pi OS , see the links Seamus has posted for other related processes which are similar. `dd` is a poor backup procedure as it generates large files which can only be restored to identical or larger SD Cards although I initially used it.

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103991/8697 for a discussion on backup, most of which is still relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original question is "I'd like to know if there is a way to reinstall Raspian without wiping out my stuff." albeit buried. "My stuff" is all of the configuration and custom installs I performed. The comments and answer all have essentially the same answer: "No".

The responses say that I should have had backups to restore from, should have done this, should have done that, etc. All good to know, and I did believe the software I was installing had a sufficient backup system, we know how that is (now).

Fortunately, I was able to stomp through the process and undo everything that was changed without any reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

`I'd like to know if there is a way to reinstall Raspian without wiping out my stuff.`

This strikes me as an ambiguous question, but without knowing exactly what "my stuff" is, this may be an answer to your question:

You can use [`image-utils`](https://github.com/seamusdemora/RonR-RPi-image-utils) to make a backup of your system. This backup is made to an image file which can be easily restored to an SD card. It takes typically, 2 - 5 minutes to update an image, and slightly longer if you're creating a **fresh**, from scratch, image. It's done from a script that relies largely on `rsync`, and so it's not a "big deal" to download it, and you can run it while your system is operating.

For example, let's say you are about to undertake some system changes that you're not quite sure about, you could proceed as follows:

1. Update your backup (2-5 minutes)
2. Make all changes needed to your system & test
3. When you're confident your changes are sound, create a new/from-scratch backup using `image-utils` (approx a 3-10 minute process), and save that under a different file name; e.g. "post-touchscreen-update".

`image-utils` gives you two simple ways to make a full system backup:

1. From scratch:

```bash
$ sudo image-utils 

# you go through a brief Q&A to let the program know if you want to add
 additional space to the image for changes. Very simple.
```

2. To update an image previously created:

```bash
$ sudo image-utils /path/to/image-to- be-updated

# no questions, simply update the image with the changed files
```

And so, had you done this ***before*** you made your changes, you would have an exact image of your system before you did whatever you did that caused it to malfunction. You could restore from that `*.img` file using one of several available tools that can write an `.img` file to anSD card (e.g. Balena Etcher for Mac, `rufus` for Windoze). If you practice this as a routine (e.g. set it up as a `cron` job), you'll always have a safe harbor to restore from.

Comment: In my original post, I mentioned that the second driver install over-wrote the backup. What's done is done, I'm looking for another recovery method.